# NullPointer exception while declining Call in Linphone

Tags: android, linphone

I have a problem with Linphone library in android. 
When I have an incoming call, if I pick up, everything is okay, but if I hang up, the application crashes.

I have a LinphoneCore private variable:

```
private LinphoneCore mLc;
```

And this is the function that crashes.

```
private void declineCall() {
    Log.e("CSR","Decline Call");
    mLc.terminateAllCalls();
}
```

Here, the output:

```
04-07 10:48:40.599: E/CSR(4409): Decline Call
04-07 10:48:40.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 10:48:40.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4409): Process: com.test.myapp, PID: 4409
04-07 10:48:40.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4409): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.linphone.core.LinphoneCore.terminateAllCalls()' on a null object reference
04-07 10:48:40.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4409):     at com.test.myapp.IncomingCallActivity.declineCall(IncomingCallActivity.java:165)
04-07 10:48:40.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4409):     at com.test.myapp.IncomingCallActivity.onClick(IncomingCallActivity.java:138)
```

I suppose that the LinphoneCore variable has to be initialized, but I dont know what I have to put.

Somebody has the same problem or can help with the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: it should be initialized before you could use it.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know what I had to put for initializing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two possible solutions reading the linphone's code and trying different options.

Solution 1:

```
private void declineCall() {
    mLc = LinphoneManager.getLcIfManagerNotDestroyedOrNull();
    if (mLc != null) {
        mLc.terminateAllCalls();
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
private void declineCall() {
    mLc = LinphoneManager.getLc();
    if (mLc != null) {
        mLc.terminateAllCalls();
    }
}
```

Now it works and doesn't crash anymore :-)